# Split AC current from one wire into two wires (+ and - DC wires) using bridge rectifier

Tags: capacitor, bridge-rectifier

I am new and a novice. I apologize if this is a ridiculous question. I have a ground/bond wire coming from the Cable TV intersystem bonding bus bar that is carrying current and a lot of "noise" on it. It is contaminating the ground rod and traveling backing into the home. I want to filter the noise out before it touches the ground rod.

In addition to using clamp-on ferrite beads, I am wondering if I could take that Cable TV bond wire current and split it into two wires using a full wave bridge rectifier creating a DC black negative wire and red positive wire so I could wire EMI filters to it?

I have heard one could attach capacitors to lower the noise or pay for various EMI filters. If there is only one wire, I am not sure how to wire the filters or capacitors that have positive and negative terminals. I have thought about using the house ground rod as the negative and the Cable TV as the positive but don't want to cut the ground rod connection.

I am most interested, curious, if it is possible to create two DC wires (one red positive and one black negative) from the one AC bond wire using a full wave bridge rectifier and capacitor. Is this ridiculous? Thoughts or suggestions? Thank you for your patience!

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you think noise "contaminating the ground rod" is a problem?

Comment: yes it *is* ridiculous. First, describe the problem you're trying to solve, with a schematic, as your 'solution' makes no sense. Any problem you're having with common mode noise can be solved by analysing the aggressor, the victim, and then using ferrite beads/filters at them and/or changing the order of connection points to the ground connections. Putting rectifiers etc into the ground connections will not solve anything, and will defeat the primary object of the ground connection, don't do it.

Comment: Show how you clamped on those ferrites. Common or differential mode? Where did you put them?

Comment: Thank you The Photon for your reply. The problem I am trying to solve is two fold. 1) take current away from flowing onto the ground rod this isn't going into the earth but back up into the home and 2) reduce eliminate the noise that is riding in from the cable TV bond, water bond and any other bond as that noise is also a problem for some people in their homes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59878/discussion-between-tonym-and-andy-aka).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The most common way to get rid of RF noise (EMI) on a single wire is to add a ferrite based filter. Purchase a large diameter (2 inch or more) toroid ferrite core of #43 material. This will resemble a donut with a large hole or a tire without a wheel.

Get several meters of insulated, solid wire and wrap it through the toroid as shown:

[image]

The wire shown in the picture looks like bare wire but it is not. It is enamel covered wire. This will not work with bare wire.

The more turns you put on the torroid, the more effective it will be. Just keep it to a neat, single layer as shown.

Once you have completed winding it, place it in series (in between a break) in the ground wire of the offending device (but do not break the main house ground) that is giving you noise problems.

There is often no magic cure for EMI. Sometimes you have to just keep trying different approaches. But what I have described is a solid starting point.

Comment: Excellent Glenn W9IQ! Thank you for the helpful advice. I have purchased similar items (coils) to what you show here, some debuzzing coils, Icstation 100uH 6A Toroid Core Inductor Copper Wire Wound Coils and Common Mode Filters / Chokes 30.0mH 2.3A 0.33RDC (Common Mode Inductor). I will definitely include them in my experimentation. Thank you!

Comment: The core material makes a big difference in effectivity. #43 material is very good for most EMI problems that you described.

Comment: Thank you Glenn W9IQ! I will enjoy playing with wrapping them as well as buying them to compare efficacy. I found some #43 here: http://www.amidoncorp.com/43-material-ferrite-toroids/

Comment: **This is a very bad idea!** See [Sara Heart's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/309107/11683). If your ground is getting "contaminated", then it's a poor ground to begin with, and you need to fix that before anything else. Not only is breaking the direct bond a code violation, inserting any series impedance puts all of your equipment connected to the cable system at risk from the high-speed surges induced by nearby lightning strikes, which is the whole point of that connection in the first place.

Comment: I absolutely agree on not cutting the main ground wire - that wasn't being advocated. However, an earth ground is not some magic RF sink. It is quite easy to ground one end of a wire to an earth ground and still use the wire as an effective antenna. The ground on buildings is only a safety mechanism.

Comment: Then you need to rewrite the part that says, *"place it in series (in between a break) in the ground wire"*.

Comment: Agreed - the edit has been done.

Comment: This is still unacceptable. The ground on buildings is not "only" a safety mechanism — it is a safety mechanism **required by code** in most jurisdictions. ALL external wiring entering a building — power, telephone, cable TV, etc. — MUST have surge protection at the point of entry that is bonded directly to the building ground. You cannot put anything in series with it; putting a clamp-on ferrite around a straight piece of wire is the most you can get away with.

Answer (score 2):

New and novice,

Until you get yourself a nice clean EARTH ground, you will be beating your head against the wall.

You MUST either get to a cold water pipe, as *close* as possible to your project, then after removing oxidation from that pipe at the connection point, connect the ground connection(also made free of oxidation), and use a nice big gauge wire, to insure the cleanest ground source possible. *How electrically clean your ground is hinges on having the lowest resistance to earth ground as possible.* 
The alternative is to use a additional grounding rod. Those are generally specified to be 5/8" diameter, driven in a minimum of 8 feet. And the code generally specifies two of them. That gives you an idea of how critical they are. So adding one more to the spot of your project is probably your best bet. 
Although I find it hard to believe your cable company is the source of your noise issue, it is likely a contributing factor, and houshold nuetrals are notoriously noisy.

*DO NOT* even think of cutting the current ground point to your house as you had mentioned! If the house ground is compromised at all, or what you do causes the current connection to corrode over time, the neutral line in the house will start having a voltage on it, and could become a shock hazard.
Especially during an electrical storm, or power line surge. Your TV's computers Etc are also likely to start going toe up. Line surges are the #1 cause of appliance failure.

Without a clean ground to start with, capacitors would be of no use.
If you have no clean ground, you are tying noise to noise through a capacitor. Ferrite beads are only of use for small ammounts of high frequency noise.

I think you get the idea.  Also more info on what you are trying to accomplish would be helpful. : )
-Sara H